# what do we call a course you do not need to attend the class and you just attend the exam?

Tags: single-word-requests

what do we call a course you do not need to attend the class and you just attend the exam? I mean you enroll for a course in the university, you study at home, and at the end of the term, you take the exam.
is this something we can see in the US or European countries? and if yes, what do we call it?

Comment: how about when you attend the class for some courses, but for others you do not need to attend the class and just passing the exam will be enough. what do we call those courses? they are part of a whole major.

Answer (score 1):

I think you call them:

> non-compulsory lectures:
>
> [Medical student attendance at non-compulsory lectures.](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17041787)

Answer (score -1):

Those courses are called Advanced placement (AP) classes or College level entry program (Clep) classes when taken by high school students to get advanced credits toward college.